# Problem requiring different versions of libgmp-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

After I run `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev` I get:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgmp-dev : Depends:
>   libgmp10 (= 2:6.1.2+dfsg-1) but 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed E:
>   Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Then trying to install `libgmp10`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp10
...
libgmp10 is already the newest version (2:6.1.2+dfsg-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

## Source of problem

I need to install **ruby-dev** package which gives me the following output after running `sudo apt install ruby-dev`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ruby-dev : Depends: ruby2.3-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then continue with `sudo apt install ruby2.3-dev`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ruby2.3-dev : Depends: libgmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then is when I try to run the original command: `sudo apt install libgmp-dev` with the above output, any ideas?

## Additional info

- Ubuntu version: artful
- `apt-cache policy libgmp-dev` gives:

  ```
  libgmp-dev:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 2:6.1.2+dfsg-1
    Version table:
       2:6.1.2+dfsg-1 500
          500 http://uy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
  ```
- `apt-cache policy libgmp10`:

  ```
      libgmp10:
        Installed: 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2
        Candidate: 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2
        Version table:
       *** 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2 100
              100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
           2:6.1.2+dfsg-1 500
              500 http://uy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`rmadison` command shows that the `libgmp10` version that I have install is from **bionic** and not from **artful**.

```
$ rmadison libgmp10
 libgmp10 | 2:5.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1 | precise | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libgmp10 | 2:5.1.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 | trusty  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libgmp10 | 2:6.1.0+dfsg-2        | xenial  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libgmp10 | 2:6.1.2+dfsg-1        | artful  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 libgmp10 | 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2        | bionic  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

## Solution

Install the specific version used by **artful**, that is `sudo apt-get install libgmp10=2:6.1.2+dfsg-1`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp10=2:6.1.2+dfsg-1                                                              
...
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:                                                                                              
  libgmp10                                                                                                                              
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.                                                            
Need to get 240 kB of archives.                                                                                                         
After this operation, 4.096 B disk space will be freed.                                                                                 
Do you want to continue? [S/n] S                                                                                                        
Get:1 http://uy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 libgmp10 amd64 2:6.1.2+dfsg-1 [240 kB]                                      
Fetched 240 kB in 1s (290 kB/s)                                                                                                         
dpkg: warning: downgrading libgmp10:amd64 from 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2 to 2:6.1.2+dfsg-1                                                         
...
Preparing to unpack .../libgmp10_2%3a6.1.2+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...                                                                         
Unpacking libgmp10:amd64 (2:6.1.2+dfsg-1) over (2:6.1.2+dfsg-2) ...                                                                     
Setting up libgmp10:amd64 (2:6.1.2+dfsg-1) ...                                                                                          
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
```

Comment: The solution seems to depend on the Ubuntu version but you haven’t mentioned your Ubuntu version in the question, please [edit it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1030203/edit).

Comment: @Melebius Yes I had, please proofread it.

Comment: OK, I found it finally but you should use version tags like [tag:17.10] for version-specific questions.

Comment: @Melebius I've found version tag irrelevant in this case.